# name 'determine_lifestyle' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm working on a project for school and running into an error and I'm having trouble debugging it.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, traits):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.traits = traits
        pass  

    def determine_lifestyle(self):
        return 'balanced'
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name + ' has a'+ ' lifestyle'
        pass


    #Do not alter or remove this method
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.first_name == other.first_name) and (self.last_name == other.last_name) and (self.traits == other.traits)`
```

now when I call the determine_lifestyle() method

```
p1_levels = {"Work": 2, "Hobbies": 2, "Socialize": 2, "Eat": 2, "Sleep":2}

person1 = Person('jamie', 'Williams', p1_levels)

determine_lifestyle(person1)
```

the compiler gives me 
**NameError: name 'determine_lifestyle' is not defined**

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the correct way to call `determine_lifestyle`. The correct way to call it is like so:

```
>>> person1.determine_lifestyle()
balanced
```

Comment: Thank you very much I'm new to this so I apologize if this was an obvious error

Comment: @bradystewart If this is worked, mark this answer as accepted. It may be helpful for future readers.